# Insert syntax error

Tags: ms-access, sql-insert, oledbcommand

I have this sql command in oledbcommand :

```
insert into tweets(iso_language_code,created_at,id_str,textbody,truncated,in_reply_to_status_id_str,in_reply_to_user_id_str,in_reply_to_screen_name,user,id_str1,username,screen_name,location,description,url,description1,followers_count,friends_count,listed_count,created_at1,favourites_count,utc_offset,time_zone,geo_enabled,verified,statuses_count,lang) values ('en','Tue Nov 05 234107 +0000 2013','397871229903716353','TrophyManager','false','null','null','null','','1401457136','DE-football','football_bot_DE','','Football news in German \/ Fu\u00dfball Nachrichten auf Deutsch\r\n#football #Fussball #German #Germany #Deutsch #Deutschland #Bundesliga #Followback #TeamFollowBack','urlhttp\/\/t.co\/vwBeatWiSO','urls','2948','2866','2','Sat May 04 051820 +0000 2013','0','3600','Berlin','false','false','13074','en')
```

I get syntax error but when i copy it to access and run, it runs.

Comment: *"when i copy it to access and run, it runs."*  Check again.  That cannot run without `INTO` following `INSERT`

Comment: I also try with into and get error.

Comment: Is it then the same error or a different error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you still get an error with `INSERT INTO`, the problem may then be due to [reserved words](http://allenbrowne.com/AppIssueBadWord.html) as field names: user; and description.

Enclose those names in square brackets to avoid confusing the db engine.

```
in_reply_to_screen_name,[user],id_str1
```

Reserved words are frustrating.  They may not always create trouble for a query run within an Access application session.  But queries run from outside Access using OleDb seem less tolerant of reserved words.

Answer (score 2):

It should be:

```
INSERT INTO Table_Name (column1,colum2,etc) VALUES (value1,value2,etc.);
```

So you forgot the INTO

Answer (score 0):

Here are the things I see wrong with your SQL statement:

1. You need to use `INSERT INTO tweets` instead of `insert tweets`
2. I am guessing you really don't want a string of ***'null'*** but rather
   would like the field to be ***Null***.  Don't use `'`.
3. You are adding a string of ***'false'*** and I am guessing you really want
   the field to be ***False***.  So you would not put the `'` around it.
4. You also have some numbers that you are adding as strings instead of
   numbers.  If they really should be numbers don't wrap them in `'`.
5. The format of your date does not appear to be valid.

So with all of the above changes your query might look like:

```
INSERT INTO tweets
(
  iso_language_code, created_at, id_str, textbody, 
  truncated, in_reply_to_status_id_str, in_reply_to_user_id_str, 
  in_reply_to_screen_name, [user], id_str1, username, screen_name,
  location, [description], url, description1, followers_count, friends_count,
  listed_count, created_at1, favourites_count, utc_offset, time_zone,
  geo_enabled, verified, statuses_count, lang
) 
VALUES (
  'en', CDATE('2013-11-05 23:41:07'), 397871229903716353,
  'TrophyManager', False, Null, Null, Null, '', 1401457136, 'DE-football',
  'football_bot_DE', '', 
  'Football news in German \/ Fu\u00dfball Nachrichten auf Deutsch\r\n#football #Fussball #German #Germany #Deutsch #Deutschland #Bundesliga #Followback #TeamFollowBack',
  'urlhttp\/\/t.co\/vwBeatWiSO', 'urls', 2948, 2866, 2,
  'Sat May 04 051820 +0000 2013', 0, 3600, 'Berlin', False, False,
  13074, 'en'
)
```

Comment: `'Tue Nov 05 234107 +0000 2013'` isn't a format I'm familiar with either.  If that's a date field, there could be problems.

Comment: ***@LittleBobbyTables***,  I updated my answer to reflect your date format issue.